# Html image gallery

Tags: html, css

[image]

I’m trying to make an image gallery, the issues i am having with the following code is that 
the images are not floating to the left because the images are different sizes. also when i click on the image to see the full size its very pig. is there a way to fix this, or maybe display half of the picture when in galley mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Image Gallery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href='css/gallery.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <?php if($images):?>
                <div class='gallery cf'>
                    <?php foreach($images as $image):?>
                    <div class='gallery-item'>
                        <a href="<?php echo $image['full'] ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['full'] ?>" ></a>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            <?php else: ?>
                There are no images 
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


.cf:before,
.cf:after{
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after{
    clear:both;
}

.container{
    max-width: 940px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.gallery{
    width:100%;
}

.gallery-item{
    float:left;
    background: #fff;
    width:19%;
    margin:1%;
    padding:2%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.gallery-item img{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Why do we need to see your PHP?  Just show the HTML markup as rendered in the browser.

Comment: The PHP is relevant in this case, as we can tell exactly how Karish is trying to set up the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code using what Simon Arnold suggested:

```
<div class='container'>
    <?php if($images):?>
    <div class='gallery cf'>
        <?php foreach($images as $image):?> 
        <a href="<?php echo $image['full'] ?>">
            <div class='gallery-item' style="background:url(<?php echo $image['full'] ?>);"> 

            </div><!-- .gallery-item -->
        </a>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <!-- .gallery cf-->
    <?php else: ?>There are no images
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<!-- .container -->
```

CSS

```
.gallery-item {
    width:number;
    height:number;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both, it work but it makes the images too zoomed in, maybe i should convert all the images to a smaller size using php

Comment: You can change `background-size:` to any thing you want, e.g. 25%, 50%, whatever. Or where you have `echo $image['full']` I'm going to assume you have other sizes other than `full` that you can substitute.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `<img>` with different sizes in the thumb gallery, use a div with a fixe dimensions, so they will float perfectly, than set the image as a background-image and add `background-size: cover;` So the image will cover the div and the overflow will be hidden.

Comment: I was just going to post this, you beat me to it :)

Comment: what do you mean by setting the background-image and add background-size: cover.

Comment: @KarishKarish you are currently using php to loop through images and then print them out as `<img>`. Instead, use a `<div>` with a fixed size and set the images as `background-image` on the `div` using CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the explications @disinfor, you beat me on this one :)

Answer (score 0):

I just build a Social media site and (2) things I do when A user uploads a pic

1. Resize image to multiple sizes for proper use / viewing (Try and keep a consistent height or width) Photoshop images to a specific height this way its consistent.
2. Use CSS to keep the image width an height from expanding out side the region.

**CSS CHANGES:**

.gallery-item img{

```
width:100%;

height:**MAKE THIS YOUR CONSTANT HEIGHT**;
```

}

It will stretch the image if its scale is off alot but you will have your answer or put it as a background in a div as listed below.

**CSS CHANGES:**

`#Pic{
    height: **MAKE THIS YOUR CONSTANT HEIGHT**;
}`

`<div id='Pic' style='background:url(picture.jpg)'></div>`

Here is a preview (although image will stretch your layout and gallery will stay organized and clean. 
[image: STAYS ORGANIZED]

[image: Consistent image width]